# Fineuploader: change _netUploaded on an extern function

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I want to allow only 6 images to be uploaded, so this is my code:

```
    jQuery('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({          
    request: {
        endpoint: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('shop/functions/submitUploadProductImage') ?>'
    },
     validation: {      
        itemLimit:6
    }
}).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.success) {

        jQuery("#images-container").append(
            '<div class="productImgContainer border-img">' +
                '<img id="productImg'+id+'" class="productImgBig" data-image="'+responseJSON.uploadName+'" data-extension="'+responseJSON.extension+'"  src="'+path+'/'+ responseJSON.uploadName +'">'+
                '<a class="deleteImage newImage" delete-id="'+id+'"></a>'+
            '</div>'
        );

        var nbImagesProd = jQuery(this).fineUploader('getNetUploads', id);          
        if (nbImagesProd == 6) {                
            jQuery(".addButton").hide();
        }       
    }
});
```

As you can see, I can get the getNetUploads via the on.complete function, and if 6 images have been uploaded, I hide the button. This works fine.

But, I use a delete function custom (not from the fineuploader) :

```
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.deleteImage', function(){    
      //I want to decrease the fineUploader _netUploaded so I can uploaded a new file
})
```

I try to set a new function in `fineupload.js`:

```
setNetUploads: function() {
   this._netUploaded--;
}
```

But I cannot call it outside of the complete call back cause I do not have the ID like the `getFunction`.

So, how can I modifiy the `_netUploaded` variable outside of any callbacks?

Comment: Why don't you just use the built-in delete feature?

Comment: I think I can build something with the integrate function, But I need to change the design of my page and I need to transform the function from a DELETE to a POST method. I guess this will not be complicated, So if they are no others easy solution, I will try to go with the built-in feature.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and your question, it's still not clear what problem you are having.  I can see that you are trying to add your own API method that decrements the internal variable that tracks net uploads so the `itemLimit` validation works as expected.  If you must modify the Fine Uploader source, it's not clear to me why you don't just add an API method and call it just as you would call any other API method.  You can call your new API method like this:

`$('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader('setNetUploads');`

I would suggest you use the built-in delete file feature and handle the DELETE request server-side.  Modifying the Fine Uploader code without a good understanding of the library is probably not a good idea, especially when you ultimately upgrade to a newer version of Fine Uploader in the future.  There is already an open case to allow the delete file feature to use POST requests, optionally.  Please see case [#801](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/801) for more details.